# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)

Tags: debian, apt

I am running on xen, Debian 5.0-i386-default. I haven't touched my vps in 2 months then last night I ran the following command:

```
myserver:/usr/bin# apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

The following packages have been kept back:
makepasswd

The following packages will be upgraded:
libc6 libc6-dev libc6-xen libmysqlclient15off locales mysql-client mysql-client-5.0 mysql-
common mysql-server mysql-server-5.0

10 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Need to get 0B/50.1MB of archives.

After this operation, 483kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y

Preconfiguring packages ...

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

I googled and it seems to be a permission thing for "dpkg". However, I cd into /usr/bin and there's no dpkg binary!!! Please help thanks

Comment: Strange. I OTOH get `Could not exec dpkg!` when `dpkg` isn't found. What command did you use to check if `dpkg` binary isn't there? Can you try `file /usr/bin/dpkg` and tell us what the output is?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here http://thelowedown.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/debian-apt-get-installs-fail-with-dpkg-error-code-100/